# Unexpected behaviour with str_replace "NA"

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I'm trying to convert a character string to numeric and have encountered some unexpected behaviour with `str_replace`.  Here's a minimum working example:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("0", "NULL", "0")

# This works, i.e. 0 NA 0
as.numeric(str_replace(x, "NULL", ""))

# This doesn't, i.e. NA NA NA
as.numeric(str_replace(x, "NULL", NA))
```

To my mind, the second example should work as it should only replace the second entry in the vector with `NA` (which is a valid value in a character vector).  But it doesn't: the inner `str_replace` converts all three entries to `NA`.

What's going on here?  I had a look through the documentation for `str_replace` and `stri_replace_all` but don't see an obvious explanation.

**EDIT:** To clarify, this is with `stringr_1.0.0` and `stringi_1.0-1` on R 3.1.3, Windows 7.

Comment: Certainly an unexpected behaviour in the source code which needs correction, you need to provide NA a string to make it working: `as.numeric(str_replace(x, "NULL", "NA"))`

Comment: Possible workaround?
`x <- c("0", "NULL", "0"); y <- x; y[y=="NULL"] <- NA; as.numeric(y)`

Comment: I must be missing something, the second example works for me `as.numeric(str_replace(x, "NULL", NA)) [1]  0 NA  0`

Comment: @PierreLafortune `stringr` used to wrap `base` functions; now it wraps `stringi` functions. You have a old version of `stringr` I guess. `gsub` behaves correctly here.

Comment: like @PierreLafortune I'm getting the correct/expected output (with both lines in my case)

Comment: @nicola CathG has the latest release and gets the correct output so not sure how OP is getting this

Comment: I had several packages loaded so I re-tried on a "fresh" session with just `stringr` (`stringr_1.0.0`) and it still works...

Comment: @CathG I am seeing the same behavior at the OP also with stringr 1.0.0 in a clean session. Platform differences...? I'm on OSX.

Comment: Strange. I have `stringr 1.0.0` and `stringi 1.0-1` (which appears to be the latest versions) and can reproduce OP's results. I'm on Ubuntu. OS dependent?

Comment: Also having `stringr 1.0.0` & `stringi 1.0-1` and get the same as OP in a clean session (on OSX)

Comment: same versions of `stringr` and `stringi`, `R 3.2.1` on Windows 7

Comment: I am also getting the OP's result with `stringr 1.0.0`, `stringi 1.0-1`, and `R 3.2.3` on Windows 7. I'm trying to trace the source now.

Comment: so more like R version related ?

Comment: Weird. Looking through the source code, first `NA` is converted to `NA_character_`, then it winds up here:  `x <- c("123", "NULL", "456"); stringi:::stri_replace_first_regex(x, "NULL", NA_character_)`. (I changed the numbers to remove any possible issues with 0). After that it descends into C code...

Comment: I was finally able to reproduce the error by updating both packages. Perhaps file a feature request.

Comment: I recommend a feature request for stringi for that :)

Comment: Don't bother, I filed an issue already https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/issues/210

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the source code of `str_replace`.

```
function (string, pattern, replacement) 
{
    replacement <- fix_replacement(replacement)
    switch(type(pattern), empty = , bound = stop("Not implemented", 
        call. = FALSE), fixed = stri_replace_first_fixed(string, 
        pattern, replacement, opts_fixed = attr(pattern, "options")), 
        coll = stri_replace_first_coll(string, pattern, replacement, 
            opts_collator = attr(pattern, "options")), regex = stri_replace_first_regex(string, 
            pattern, replacement, opts_regex = attr(pattern, 
                "options")), )
}
<environment: namespace:stringr>
```

This leads to finding `fix_replacement`, which is at [Github](https://github.com/hadley/stringr/blob/5f9319b5cd365372c950da8de0360c30f60b776a/R/replace.r), and I've put it below too. If you run it in your main environment, you find out that `fix_replacement(NA)` returns `NA`. You can see that it relies on `stri_replace_all_regex`, which is from the `stringi` package.

```
fix_replacement <- function(x) {
    stri_replace_all_regex(
        stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "$", "\\$"),
        "(?<!\\\\)\\\\(\\d)",
        "\\$$1")
}
```

The interesting thing is that `stri_replace_first_fixed` and `stri_replace_first_regex` both return `c(NA,NA,NA)` when run with your parameters (your `string`, `pattern`, and `replacement`). The problem is that `stri_replace_first_fixed` and `stri_replace_first_regex` are C++ code, so it gets a little trickier to figure out what's happening.

`stri_replace_first_fixed` can be found [here](https://github.com/jeroenooms/stringi/blob/4d13bdd25a4ff4ee4e74ad2d7f7f32abf5a9b7eb/src/stri_search_fixed_replace.cpp).

`stri_replace_first_regex` can be found [here](https://github.com/jeroenooms/stringi/blob/4d13bdd25a4ff4ee4e74ad2d7f7f32abf5a9b7eb/src/stri_search_regex_replace.cpp).

As far as I can discern with limited time and my relatively rusty C++ knowledge, the function `stri__replace_allfirstlast_fixed` checks the `replacement` argument using `stri_prepare_arg_string`. According to the [documentation](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/functions/stri_prepare_arg_string) for that, it will throw an error if it encounters an NA. I don't have time to fully trace it beyond this, but I would suspect that this error may be causing the odd return of all NAs.

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug in the `stringi` package but now it is [fixed](https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/commit/fb97b40152792c5db896420f0991f0cbed1cf789) (recall that `stringr` is based on `stringi` - the former shall be affected too).

With the most recent development version we get:

```
stri_replace_all_fixed(c("1", "NULL"), "NULL", NA)
## [1] "1" NA
```

Comment: I still get the issue using stringr 1_2_0 which calls stringi_1.1.5? Though see the issue was closed though on github, https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/110 Any idea what is hapening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using dplyr's  `across` method and the stringr package.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","null","e"),
                 y=c("g","null","h","k"))  

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),str_replace,"null",NA_character_))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to answer this problem as shown [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/124), using `NA_character_`

## Short answer to the question:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("0", "NULL", "0")
y <- as.numeric(str_replace(x, "NULL", NA_character_))
```

Produces:

```
> y
[1]  0 NA  0
> typeof(y)
[1] "double"
```

## Going further

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
# create a dummy dataset
ex = starwars %>% select(name, hair_color, homeworld) %>% head(6)
print(ex)
# lets say you want to replace all "Tatooine" by NA
# this produce the expected output
ex %>% mutate(homeworld = str_replace_all(homeworld, pattern = "Tatooine", NA_character_))

# HOWEVER,
# From Hadley's comment: "str_replace() has to replace parts of a string and replacing part of a string with NA doesn't make sense."
# then be careful using this method, see the example below:
ex %>% mutate(hair_color = str_replace_all(hair_color, pattern = "brown", NA_character_))
# all air colors with "brown", including "blond, grey" (Owen Lars, line 6) are now NA
```

## Outputs

```
> print(ex)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   name               hair_color    homeworld
   <chr>              <chr>         <chr>    
 1 Luke Skywalker     blond         Tatooine 
 2 C-3PO              NA            Tatooine 
 3 R2-D2              NA            Naboo    
 4 Darth Vader        none          Tatooine 
 5 Leia Organa        brown         Alderaan 
 6 Owen Lars          brown, grey   Tatooine  

> ex %>% mutate(homeworld = str_replace_all(homeworld, pattern = "Tatooine", NA_character_))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   name               hair_color    homeworld
   <chr>              <chr>         <chr>    
 1 Luke Skywalker     blond         NA       
 2 C-3PO              NA            NA       
 3 R2-D2              NA            Naboo    
 4 Darth Vader        none          NA       
 5 Leia Organa        brown         Alderaan 
 6 Owen Lars          brown, grey   NA         

 > ex %>% mutate(hair_color = str_replace_all(hair_color, pattern = "brown", NA_character_))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   name               hair_color    homeworld
   <chr>              <chr>         <chr>    
 1 Luke Skywalker     blond         Tatooine 
 2 C-3PO              NA            Tatooine 
 3 R2-D2              NA            Naboo    
 4 Darth Vader        none          Tatooine 
 5 Leia Organa        NA            Alderaan 
 6 Owen Lars          NA            Tatooine
```